# Html 5 video controls make me not able to use my navigation's drop down menu

Tags: controls, html5-video, navbar

The title says it all.

I have a navbar at the top of my site (Not fixed) with a dropdown menu. The problem now is that when I want to use the dropdown menu and it goes across an html5 video player the controls of the video player take priority so I can continue to click through my list.

Also, no z-index has been used anywhere in the site.

[visualisation of what my problem is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s46HD.gif)

I would appreciate any little bit of help I can get.

Comment: Just tried document.getElementById("myVideo").controls = false;. That did disable the controls but still made the navbar dropdown menu not work above the video.

Comment: put  z-index to your drop down menu and give a value 9

Comment: Yes! That is it giving the ul of the menu z index 1 or higher solved it. But only the menu, not the entire navbar.

Comment: fine you got that right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the z-index of just the menu, not the navbar to a higher z-index than the video fixes my problem.